# Drawing a ProgressBar on top of other views programmatically

Tags: android

I would like to create a Java method that's capable of drawing progress indicators on top of different views (ImageViews, Buttons, etc.. ). 
So that I can just call **showProgess(View v)** and **hideProgress(View v)** and the progress indicator will overlay only the passed view. What are the steps needed to achieve this?

Comment: Well nobody is going to write your code for you. What have you tried so far? And what were the problems you encountered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if its possible by just "writing a method"

If we have TextView and you want to show progress as overlay of it you can:

Create ViewTextViewWithProgress class:

ViewTextViewWithProgress extends RelativeLayout {

(...)
}

Then use RelativeLayout layout and put into it ordinary TextView and you progress indicator.

Use your ViewTextViewWithProgress  instead of ordinary TextView

A good place to start creating custom views:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html